# Simple function help

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, functions

I am not familiar with Fourier series, (I'm guessing that has something to do with what I want), and I want to know if someone could construct a convergent series for a function $f(x)$ with the property that if $x\equiv b\mod{a}$, $f(x)=1$, and if it's not congruent to $b \mod a$, $f(x)=0$.

Comment: Eerr....I think you just did construct such a function! What did you expect?

Comment: I need it in terms of continuous functions, like how one can represent the floor function with an infinite sum of sine functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f(x)={1\over a}\sum_{t=0}^{a-1}e^{2\pi it(x-b)/a}$$

Comment: Gerry how did you come up with this? Also thanks

Comment: It's a standard trick in parts of Number Theory, where it is used for turning the number of solutions of a congruence into an exponential sum, all the better to estimate it.